# Angular 5 application display blank screen IE 11 with this error in the console SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier (windows 10)

Tags: javascript

All polyfills are updated,target set to es5.
included the tag  in the head at the top (before the styles).
issue is still occurring after trying all these.

what could still be causing this error SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier

Comment: Could you provide us with `polyfill.ts` configuration?

Comment: Please provide more info. Which error shows in the F12 console?

Comment: @Jannes this is the error : SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier (main.4ca0ad3395c3c11705c2.bundle.js (1,1574))

Comment: @JózefPodlecki here some code from file:/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

Comment: @JózefPodlecki I HOPE THIS HEPLS, EVERYTHING BELOW THIS IS IS ACTIVE /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/  import 'classlist.js';  --ALSO ACTIVE --npm install --save classlist.js